# Deployed version of NodeJS site not loading on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am doing my first deployment on AWS (using Elastic Beanstalk), and I am completely new to this.

I built a personal website using NodeJS / Express, and on my local machine it loads just fine. Once I was ready to deploy a v1, I created an AWS account and set up a new EBS application environment for Node. I set up the static files to load from /public, set my node version, and set the launch command as node app.js, but those were the only options I changed.

I zipped up my site (using CNTL + Click -> Compress on a selection of all site files) and uploaded that zip, and after some time, it came up all green. Clicking the link to load my site though, I get a half finished version. Looking at my console, I see that I am getting 4 files as 404, and because of that, 4 failures from RequireJS.

These 4 files are backbone views, and are contained in a folder with 4 other JS files that are all loading just fine (I can open them in the chrome dev tools source tab from the deployed version). I am confused how just these 4 files would go missing.

Is there some way to FTP into where ever my files are contained, to confirm the files are in fact not present? And barring that, what steps are available to figure out what is occurring here? Like I said, it looks and loads just fine locally, and I am at a loss as to where to even start debugging something like this. The AWS docs I have read so far only tell me to do exactly what I have been doing.

Repo for the project is here: https://github.com/RyanMG/trustycode

And the deployment is here: http://trustycode.elasticbeanstalk.com/

The files it is having trouble with are under public/javascript/views/ (CodeView, AboutView, PhotoView, DesignView)

Any ideas / advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to FTP into where ever my files are contained, to confirm the files are in fact not present?

You can ssh into the EC2 instance of the Elastic Beanstalk app using your pem file. 
Check files in /var/app/current

Comment: Jesus. So this long form approach lead me to the real problem. Grunt seems to be case insensitive when choosing to overwrite files. My coffee files were named *View, and the JS files they were compiling to   were *VIew (cap I). Locally it did not seem to find this problem, but when deployed it became a one. So stupid user error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but that is one of those common gotchas I found myself switching to OSX from GNU/LINUX at work. OSX is case insensitive; linux world is case sensitive.